# Month is auto selected to JANUARY in CalenderView while selecting date from timepicker Dialog

Tags: java, android

here i have stored day,month, and year of timepickerDialog into a string and set it back to CalenderView
but having issue in just MONTH that is auto selected to JAN.
NOTE: date and year are working fine

```
     String Date= day +"/"+ month +"/"+ year;
                try {
                    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat= new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
                    simpleCalendarView.setDate(simpleDateFormat.parse(Date).getTime(),true,true);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: Show the code where you assign month value

Comment: I am getting date from TimePickerDialog and setting in calenderView by calling .setDate() method as shown above .

Comment: String Date= day +"/"+ month +"/"+ year;

Comment: here in this string Date , "month" is value that is fetched from TimePickerDialog